# PDFTK and PDF2PS not playing well together

Tags: php, linux, pdf

I have set up PDFTK so that I can rotate a pdf 90 degrees to print it landscape mode. Have had no luck rotating using lpr, so I am trying to rotate before I send to the printer.

Once I use PDFTK the created PDF files appears to be rotated perfectly. It then gets translated into a postscript file, using pdf2ps, and when it is sent to the printer, or rendered and opened, it is the original non rotated version.

I had been using PDF90 which worked great, but due to conflicts on the production server that this needs to run on, PDF90 is not available.

Any ideas as to why the postscript file remains non rotated?

Answer (score 0):

When talking about "page rotation" with PDF files, what you mean normally is the ***viewing*** of the page as it is displayed on ***screen***.

What ***you*** seem to imply is the rotations of the ***printed*** page ***image*** on the page ***media***. Could you clarify please?